# Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic. Then $\mbox{Re}f+\mbox{Im}f$ has not a minimum.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be  an open and connected set. Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic. Supposed that $f$ is not constant. Show that $\mbox{Re}f+\mbox{Im}f$ has not a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $g(z)=e^{(i-1)f(z)}$. Note that $g$ is holomorphic in $U$, furthermore:
$$|g(z)|=e^{-\left(\mbox{Re}f(z)+\mbox{Im}f(z)\right)}.$$
If $\mbox{Re}f+\mbox{Im}f$ has a minimum, then $|g|$ has maximum in $U$, then by Maximum Modulus Principle  $g$ is constant. Therefore, $f$ is constant. Contradiction.